# How to copy protocol activation link to clipboard in UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to copy a link to the users clipboard with they click a button after they can paste in an email or in a message chat like Teams or slack. My code that runs after the button is clicked looks somewhat like this

```
    var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
    dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy | DataPackageOperation.Link;
    var uri = new Uri("myapplink:?query&param1=value1");
    dataPackage.SetApplicationLink(uri);
    dataPackage.SetText("Really cool link to my app")
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
    Clipboard.Flush();
```

But this only copies "Really cool link to my app" and not [Really cool link to my app](http://myapplink:) in my message.

Anyone done this before and can give some help?

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid call `Flush` method, it may destroy the data.

**Set Data**

```
var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy | DataPackageOperation.Link;
var uri = new Uri("myapp:privacy-webcam", UriKind.Absolute);
dataPackage.SetApplicationLink(uri);
dataPackage.SetText("Really cool link to my app");
Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
```

**Get Data**

```
DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();
if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.ApplicationLink) && dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
{
    var uri = await dataPackageView.GetApplicationLinkAsync();
    var text = await dataPackageView.GetTextAsync();               
}
```

Comment: @Nico-Zhu-MSFT After copying to the clipboard I would like to be able to paste this link in either outlook or Teams or Slack.  Is that possible?  I know OneNote is able to generate that type of link but I'm not sure how they have done it.

Comment: If you just copy the data to outlook with Ctrl+ V, we suggest you store the url with `SetText` method.

Comment: @Nico-Shu-MSFT How do I make that text a clickable link and not just text?

Comment: Is there any way to make it so whats copied to the clipboard is a hyperlink? 
```dataPackage.SetText("<a href=\"myapp:privacy-webcam\">link</a>")``` So not appear to work.

Comment: `<a href=\"myapp:privacy-webcam\">link</a>` will be pasted into outlook with string format, we need add  hyperlink in outlook manually.